# How to use saml data to login

Tags: python, powershell, saml, saml-2.0, onelogin

We are trying to port the oneLogin saml logic to Python, i am able to successfully get the $saml result from the 1st part. However, getting 500 error code for the part that logs in to my app. Could someone point to to the right path to rewrite the login to app part by using Python requests package from powershell? Thanks.

```
function session () {
    $oneloginUrl = "https://api.onelogin.com/api/v3/saml/assertion"
    #get saml assertion
    $request = @{
        api_key='abc'
        username='abc@abc.com' 
        password='abc'
        app_id='123'
    }
    $json = $request | ConvertTo-Json

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod $oneloginUrl -Method Post -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json'
    $saml = $response.data

    #login to myapp
    $myappUrl = "https://myapp.com/sso/response"
    $form = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormObject -ArgumentList "test","post","submit"
    $form.Fields.add("RelayState","/" )
    $form.Fields.add("SAMLResponse", $saml)
    $r=Invoke-WebRequest $myappUrl -SessionVariable myapp -Body $form.fields -Method post
    return $myapp        
}
```

Comment: Use a tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to intercept your SAML messages from Python and Powershell. See what's different in the messages and fix accordingly.

Comment: Looks like you're manually getting an assertion from onelogin then POSTing it to your app that is using SAML2 WBSSO profile which expects a SAMLResponse base64 encoded. As it didn't ask for the response it looks like you might be using IdP initiated login. Does your app support that? What comes back from onelogin? An Assertion or a SAMLResponse? The SAMLResponse audience might not be what your app expects either